# Can OpenVPN avoid DUO 2FA is some cases?

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn

Is there a way to avoid Duo 2FA for some accounts when connecting to openvpn?

Basically the openvpn client starts a connection to openvpn server which should skip DUO module based on a account whitelist and just authenticate by userid and password.

Comment: probably i'd look to use freeradius to do the authentication and act as a shim layer to make decisions about which accounts get which access steps.  I can't guarantee that will work for you, but it probably will.

Answer (score 0):

We once set this up using pam_per_user (which was able to use different authentication sources based on the username).

Same functionality can be obtained by using a script for auth-user-pass-verify:

```
auth-user-pass-verify /opt/openvpn/scripts/openVPN-authenticate.pl via-env
```